# How can I get the current state of element in react for rendering progress bar?

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar, progress

```
handlePercent=()=>{
    if (this.state.phone!=="") {
        this.setState(() => ({
            percent: this.state.percent + 20,
        }));
    } else if(this.state.website!==""){
        this.setState(() => ({
            percent: this.state.percent + 20,
        }));
    }
    return this.state.percent;
};
```

I have the above function for handling the percent state, but even if the state of object, for example phone is not null it does not give me the right state. I checked phone state for example with console log and it s empty.

Bellow is there I call the percent object. I have used "react-sweet-progress"

```
 <div className="percent">
        <p>Your profile is {this.state.percent}% complete:</p>
        <Progress percent={this.handlePercent()}/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more of your component's code? You are also checking if  `phone` is NOT EQUAL to `""`, is that expected? Because in that case if phone is an empty string, then it won't reach your code to add 20 percent.

Comment: Yeah, I need to to add 20 percent just if the field is not empty (for example phone field here), if it is, percent will return it's current state

Answer (score 1):

You should use `prevState` in `setState` instead of using `this.state`

```
handlePercent = () => {
    if (this.state.phone !== "") {
        this.setState(prevState=> ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 20,
        }))
    } else if(this.state.website!==""){
        this.setState(prevState=> ({
            percent: prevState.percent + 20,
        }))
    }
    // don't return state
}
```

And pass `this.state.percent` to `Progress`

```
<Progress percent={this.state.percent}/>
```

And call `handlePercent` in some other place in the code.

The reason for `don't return state` is that when you call `this.setState` it will rerender the component and make `this.state.percent` the correct percent. If you return `this.state.percent`, it will return the wrong data.

Please add the full logic of the component for more understanding of how to do what you want.

Comment: My only potential edit here is your `this.state.phone !== "" || this.state.website !== ""` makes your `else if` unreachable. So you could remove the `else if` condition in this case as your updated if statement handles both scenarios.

Comment: @segFault that was a typo, sorry

Comment: `progress` component is from `react-sweet-progress` package

Comment: @StanciuPatrick We are both referring to YOUR component's code.

Comment: @StanciuPatrick I mean you need to show your full component, the parent component that renders `Progress` and where does `this.state.phone` comes from. Does it comes from a async call?

Comment: Phone's states does come from database. Here is the full code (https://codepen.io/stanciu-patrick/pen/BaygaPv)